# Drag data-uri images from extension's content_script into Google Docs

Tags: php, image, server, google-docs, content-script

I have a **data uri** and I need to get an **img tag** out of it that references some url.

**Why would I want to do that?**

I'm developing an extension that contains an overlay over Google Docs and displays an image inside of it. The user should then be able to drag that image into the document to use it. If I include the image via a normal url to some stock photo, everything works perfectly. However, if I include the image via a data uri, Google Docs fails to load that image.

**My idea for a solution:**

```
<img src="http://some-imaginary-host.org/getpng/?data=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...">
```

This image tag would contain a loadable url that returns a standard .png file. That host wouldn't have to store any data, just do the basic (I hope) conversion and correct headers.

**Now my questions:**

- Would my idea work in practice or are there any obstacles I haven't thought of?
- Is there any easier way of doing this that might not even require a host?

Comment: I'm unclear what kind of job that host would be doing…!?

Comment: I tried to explain it better now, is it more clear? If not, what don't you understand? I just need Google Docs be able to download a png file from a url that takes a data uri as its parameter.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense now. The biggest problem with this is probably that you'll hit the maximum length of URLs which a server will process/browsers will send. Or can you guarantee a certain maximum size for your images? As for the questions… We don't recommend 3rd party hosts. How easy it is for you we don't know; it's just decoding a data URI to binary and outputting that, plus setting some headers. Overall it's not a very advanced task. Have you tried anything that you're stuck on?

Comment: No, I haven't had the time to look into it yet. I searched for hosts like that and didn't find any, but maybe I just worded my google queries wrong, so I asked here as well, in the hopes that there would be an easier way of achieving the simple goal of dragging images into documents. That php stuff seems to be relatively simple, I'll give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: If anything you'll want to rephrase your question to just ask about dragging data URIs onto Google Docs. Maybe there's something else. The rest of the question is, as stated, not really answerable.

Answer (score 0):

So here's my solution:

**Steps:**

- Server converts data uri to correct url (code below)
- Chrome Extension Script inserts the image by manually opening dialogs (this is honestly the best thing I could come up with, even though it's bad everything else didn't work..)

**Server script:**

```
<?php
// NOTE: This code is far from perfect, but it does the job (at least in my own-use case)
// NOTE: Parameter has to be sanitized before sending, to avoid url-escaping
// Validate the parameter
if(!preg_match('/data:(.*_.*;base64,[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*)/', $_GET["data"])) {
    die("Not a valid parameter.");
}

// Decode the received url-safe data into valid base64
$convertedUri = strtr($_GET["data"], "._-", "+/=");

// Split the data uri into parts
$uri = explode(";", $convertedUri);

$contentType = explode(":", $uri[0])[1];
$base64 = explode(",", $uri[1])[1];
$data = base64_decode($base64);

// Try to convert the received data into an image
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: '.$contentType);
    echo $data;
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    die("Error: " . $base64);
}
?>
```